# Pub/Sub design pattern to implement kafka-node library in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, apache-kafka, kafka-node

I am using `kafka-node` module in my NodeJs Microservise project. Here I want a Pub/Sub (publisher and subscriber) design pattern in Functional programming paradigm.

### producer.js

```js
  const client = new kafka.KafkaClient({
    kafkaHost: process.env.KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS,
  });
  const producer = new kafka.Producer(client);

  producer.on("ready", () => {
    producer.createTopics(
      ["topic1", "topic2", "topic3"],
      true,
      console.log,
    );
  ...
  ...
  producer.send(
      [
        {
          topic: "topic1",
          messages: JSON.stringify(req.body),
        },
      ],
      console.log,
    );
```

### consumer.js

```js
  const client = new kafka.KafkaClient({
    kafkaHost: process.env.KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS,
  });
  console.log(client);
  const consumer = new kafka.Consumer(
    client,
    [{ topic: "topic1" }],
    {
      autoCommit: false,
    },
  );

  consumer.on("message", (message) => {
    doSomeAction(JSON.parse(message.value));
  });

  consumer.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

## Expectation

A Function Programming module named like -`KafkaLib`

```js
const kafkaLib = KafkaLib({kafkaHost: process.env.KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS});
...
...
kafkaLib.publish("topic1", req.body);
...
...
kafkaLib.subscribe("topic1", (data)=>{
   doSomeAction(data.value);
});
```

Comment: Want a functional approach for a scalable implementation

Comment: You should write the code and if you encounter any problem, ask for help to solve that specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really related to Kafka. JS functions are top-level objects, so this

```
producer.on("ready", () => {
    producer.createTopics(
      ["topic1", "topic2", "topic3"],
      true,
      console.log,
    );
});
```

Could be re-written as

```
const onReady = () => {
    producer.createTopics(
      ["topic1", "topic2", "topic3"],
      true,
      console.log,
    );
};

producer.on("ready", onReady);
```

But, it's not clear what that helps you with. This is no more scalable than the first version.

[NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/kafka#incoming) is more functional with classes and event-handlers.